# FFMPEG spends 6 seconds to create first video frame after i feed first image to it?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to convert a sequence of images to a video, i find that after i feed first image to it and almost 6 seconds later ffmpeg output first video frame to me.

I use command as follow:

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 100 -i pipe:0 -f flv -r 100 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -bufsize 2M -codec:v libx264 -codec:a libmp3lame -bf 0 -muxdelay 0.001 -s 478x850 -b:v 2M pipe:1
```

Is my options is right?

Or others led to this result?

How can i get first video frame quickly once i feed the first frame?

Comment: Reduce the probesize and analyseduration

Comment: Sorry for late reply, your advice works for me!

Comment: By the way, options are probesize and analyzeduration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change probesize & analyzeduration options